# Why is location services not working as background task?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, cllocationmanager, appdelegate

In my app there is a location (area) to be watched. When the device is moved away from that location (it could be a distance as small as 5 - 10 meters) an AlertView pops up and a sound is played. When the app is in the background an local notification is generated. Tapping or sliding the notification brings the app to the front. This works fine. However, when running in the background the location updates stoppes after 15-16 minutes or so. The arrow is removed from the status bar. Bringing the app to the front the AlertView pops up and the sound is played. As far as I can see is location services getting a new fix on the current position and is the AlertView shown because the initial distance is greater then the area to be watched. Due to the small areas to be watched I think I could not use "significant-changes" or "didExitRegion". Is that true?

I set the tag in the info.plist to "App registers for location updates" in "required background modes".

Is there anyone out there who has a clou about what's goiing on?
Do I have to put some code in - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {} and if so.... what should that be?

Thanks in advance,

Regards,

Adri

Comment: For the precision you need significantLocationChange won't suffice. In your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method are you checking for the UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey key?

Comment: @onnoweb No, this is my method in the appDelegate.m. - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
Please advice.

Comment: You should check if the options argument to that method contains UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey. When you register for location notifications in your Info.plist file then iOS calls your app in the background using that method with that key in the options dictionary.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: @onnoweb I think you mean this? if ([launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] ) {
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
} <- add to the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method?

Comment: @onnoweb Thank you for helping me out. Was reading up on this and now I'm nore confused as ever. (Sorry, I'm a newbie) In the docs from apple the mentioned key is used in combination with the "significant-changes" methods. Please help me out here, I'm searching for a solution for about 2 days now. What do I have to put where..... I'm feeling very stupid right now ;-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24839/discussion-between-adri-oosterwijk-and-onnoweb)

Answer (score 0):

before startUpdatingLocation you can set your CLLocationManager's desiredAccuracy and distanceFilter fields for desired precission